# Increment a column based on number of records in a interval pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame like below in `pyspark`

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
[(1,'Y','Y',0,0,0,2,'Y','N','Y','Y'),
(2,'N','Y',2,1,2,3,'N','Y','Y','N'),
(3,'Y','N',3,1,0,0,'N','N','N','N'),
(4,'N','Y',5,0,1,0,'N','N','N','Y'),
(5,'Y','N',2,2,0,1,'Y','N','N','Y'),
(6,'Y','Y',0,0,3,6,'Y','N','Y','N'),
(7,'N','N',1,1,3,4,'N','Y','N','Y')
],
('id', 'compatible', 'product', 'ios', 'pc', 'other', 'devices', 'customer', 'subscriber', 'circle', 'smb')
)


df.show()

+---+----------+-------+---+---+-----+-------+--------+----------+------+---+
| id|compatible|product|ios| pc|other|devices|customer|subscriber|circle|smb|
+---+----------+-------+---+---+-----+-------+--------+----------+------+---+
|  1|         Y|      Y|  0|  0|    0|      2|       Y|         N|     Y|  Y|
|  2|         N|      Y|  2|  1|    2|      3|       N|         Y|     Y|  N|
|  3|         Y|      N|  3|  1|    0|      0|       N|         N|     N|  N|
|  4|         N|      Y|  5|  0|    1|      0|       N|         N|     N|  Y|
|  5|         Y|      N|  2|  2|    0|      1|       Y|         N|     N|  Y|
|  6|         Y|      Y|  0|  0|    3|      6|       Y|         N|     Y|  N|
|  7|         N|      N|  1|  1|    3|      4|       N|         Y|     N|  Y|
+---+----------+-------+---+---+-----+-------+--------+----------+------+---+
```

Now I want to create a new column `p_no` in the data frame by assigning the same value for group of records. For example two records is a group

I mean I want to assign value `0` to first two records and increment the value by `1` for the next two records and so on

Expected result:

```
+---+----------+-------+---+---+-----+-------+--------+----------+------+---+----+
| id|compatible|product|ios| pc|other|devices|customer|subscriber|circle|smb|p_no|
+---+----------+-------+---+---+-----+-------+--------+----------+------+---+----+
|  1|         Y|      Y|  0|  0|    0|      2|       Y|         N|     Y|  Y|   1|
|  2|         N|      Y|  2|  1|    2|      3|       N|         Y|     Y|  N|   1|
|  3|         Y|      N|  3|  1|    0|      0|       N|         N|     N|  N|   2|
|  4|         N|      Y|  5|  0|    1|      0|       N|         N|     N|  Y|   2|
|  5|         Y|      N|  2|  2|    0|      1|       Y|         N|     N|  Y|   3|
|  6|         Y|      Y|  0|  0|    3|      6|       Y|         N|     Y|  N|   3|
|  7|         N|      N|  1|  1|    3|      4|       N|         Y|     N|  Y|   4|
+---+----------+-------+---+---+-----+-------+--------+----------+------+---+----+
```

I applied the `row_number` function like below

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

df1 = df.withColumn("p_no",f.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy()))
```

The output is below

```
df1.show()  

+---+----------+-------+---+---+-----+-------+--------+----------+------+---+----+
| id|compatible|product|ios| pc|other|devices|customer|subscriber|circle|smb|p_no|
+---+----------+-------+---+---+-----+-------+--------+----------+------+---+----+
|  1|         Y|      Y|  0|  0|    0|      2|       Y|         N|     Y|  Y|   1|
|  2|         N|      Y|  2|  1|    2|      3|       N|         Y|     Y|  N|   2|
|  3|         Y|      N|  3|  1|    0|      0|       N|         N|     N|  N|   3|
|  4|         N|      Y|  5|  0|    1|      0|       N|         N|     N|  Y|   4|
|  5|         Y|      N|  2|  2|    0|      1|       Y|         N|     N|  Y|   5|
|  6|         Y|      Y|  0|  0|    3|      6|       Y|         N|     Y|  N|   6|
|  7|         N|      N|  1|  1|    3|      4|       N|         Y|     N|  Y|   7|
|  8|         Y|      Y|  1|  1|    2|      0|       Y|         Y|     N|  N|   8|
+---+----------+-------+---+---+-----+-------+--------+----------+------+---+----+
```

I am not sure what I need to do.
How can I achieve what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rounding the row number divided by 2 should do the job:

```
df2 = df.withColumn(
    "p_no",
    f.round(f.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(f.lit(None)))/2).cast('int')
)

df2.show()
+---+----------+-------+---+---+-----+-------+--------+----------+------+---+----+
| id|compatible|product|ios| pc|other|devices|customer|subscriber|circle|smb|p_no|
+---+----------+-------+---+---+-----+-------+--------+----------+------+---+----+
|  1|         Y|      Y|  0|  0|    0|      2|       Y|         N|     Y|  Y|   1|
|  2|         N|      Y|  2|  1|    2|      3|       N|         Y|     Y|  N|   1|
|  3|         Y|      N|  3|  1|    0|      0|       N|         N|     N|  N|   2|
|  4|         N|      Y|  5|  0|    1|      0|       N|         N|     N|  Y|   2|
|  5|         Y|      N|  2|  2|    0|      1|       Y|         N|     N|  Y|   3|
|  6|         Y|      Y|  0|  0|    3|      6|       Y|         N|     Y|  N|   3|
|  7|         N|      N|  1|  1|    3|      4|       N|         Y|     N|  Y|   4|
+---+----------+-------+---+---+-----+-------+--------+----------+------+---+----+
```

Or you can just round the id divided by 2, if the id is continuous.

Comment: Here I gave a sample df but `df1 = df.withColumn("p_no", f.round(f.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('product'))/5).cast('int'))` This gives me different result. What I want is in the `df` take first two records without considering any columns and assign `0` as the value of new column. Then increment value of new column by `1` for next two records

Comment: If you don't want to consider any columns, then you can order by `f.lit(None)`. See my edited answer?